# How can I keep 'code tunnel' running in the background?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, vscode-remote

Has somebody here figured out how to keep `code tunnel` running after I close the terminal?

I typically log in to my terminal via SSH, but would like to keep the tunnel intact so that I can just always comfortably access VSCode in the browser whenever I'm connected to the internal network via VPN. Any tips? Disown did not work for me, nor did starting up a tmux container, and running `code tunnel` inside.

To clarify, I use `fish` shell. First, I started the tunnel using `code tunnel > ct_out 2> tc_err &`, then I used `ps -u` to find the PID of the process, which I disowned using `disown PID`.

Comment: Related: https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/disown.html and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3886/550426

Comment: it's still not clear to me why your attempt wasn't working. what did you see from the output of `ps -u` that you took to be the PID of VS Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in [user](/users/11107541)'s comment, in the fish documentation:

https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/disown.html

I ran `code tunnel > ct_out 2> tc_err &; disown` in one line, and it's been running stably since.

Answer (score 9):

Try `code tunnel service install` to install as a service.  See `code tunnel service --help` for a bit more info.